# Behave - command not found in Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, cucumber, python-behave, cucumber-python

When trying to run behave in the Mac terminal, a command not found error is raised, even tho I've installed behave using pip3:

```
user_name features % pip3 install -U behave
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: behave in /Users/gamunteanu/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (1.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11 in /Users/gamunteanu/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from behave) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parse-type>=0.4.2 in /Users/gamunteanu/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from behave) (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: parse>=1.8.2 in /Users/gamunteanu/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from behave) (1.19.0)
```

Any ideas? Can't seem to figure it out

Comment: If you do a `which behave` in terminal what do you get?

Comment: it says behave not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

User-specific bin directory is not in the path.

1. open your shell profile in nano editor
   nano ~/.zshrc
2. Add user Bin Directory to PATH:
   export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"
   save the file and restart your terminal 'source ~/.zshrc' to apply the changes
3. check the behave version
   behave --version